# Ktor how to handle an empty response

Tags: kotlin, serialization, ktor

I use Ktor and a line like this `myentity = client.get(url)` to get and deserialize my entity from API response. It works fine while API returns something, but once API has nothing to return and sends HTTP 204 response, it fails with io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException.

I want to find a way how to make client.get() return null instead of throwing that exception. I searched for a solution quite much, but failed to find it. It seems that `HttpResponseValidator` in initialization of HttpClient might help somehow, but I only find a way how to throw another exception from it, but did not understand how to change a return value.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the `NoTransformationFoundException` and assign `null` to `myentity` if an exception is thrown. Here is an example:

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json

suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
        }
    }

    val response = try {
        client.get("https://httpbin.org/status/204").body<HttpBin>()
    } catch (cause: NoTransformationFoundException) {
        null
    }

    println(response?.origin)
}

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
class HttpBin(val origin: String)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I thought about it either, but I was not sure that it is OK to catch an exception for a normal flow. Is this approach appropriate in Kotlin? I am pretty new in it, but in .NET I got used to use exceptions only to handle some errors.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a normal flow. This approach is OK in Kotlin. How would you write a method in .NET that returns the content of a file as a string or `null` if the file doesn't exist?

Comment: In a short form I would write something like that `String s = File.Exists("") ? File.ReadAllText("") : null`. In a longer form it would be presented with `if`, but it does not matter. Anyway, if somebody from my team implemented this functionality through `try...catch` it would be a bad smell for me and I would ask him to fix it.

Comment: By a normal flow, I mean that the fact that API returns nothing is totally acceptable - there is no criminal in it, which is confirmed by 2XX (namely, 204) status code. For me, exceptions catching is more appropriate in case of 4XX, 5XX codes which mean that really something bad and unexpected happened.

Comment: The thing is that you don't just receive a raw body but also transform it into a specific type and you can't know ahead of time is it possible or not. My example with files is bad because you can check a file's existence. Maybe, an example, where you want to write a method that returns a byte array received from a socket or `null` if a `SocketException` is thrown in case a time-out value was exceeded, is more appropriate.

Comment: I see your point and agree with it. That said, I would prefer if Ktor had some option like `returnNullIfEmpty` for its serializer. In my opinion it would make code clearer and more elegant. Anyway, thank you very much for you help and time spent once more. I will use your recommendation in my code.