# Ktor handle empty response for arrays

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, ktor-client

I have recently started using Ktor and got stuck at the very beginning itself.

I have a very simple response, which could have content like below -

```
{
  "result": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "Name": "Danish",
      "Credit": "80"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Kumar",
      "Credit": "310"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or it could be like this -

```
{
  "result": false,
  "data": [],
  "message": "No data available, use default user",
  "default": [
    {
      "Name": "Default User",
      "Credit": "100"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my response class is like -

```
@Serializable
data class UserResponse(
    @SerialName("result") var result: Boolean? = null,
    @SerialName("data") var data: ArrayList<User?>? = null,
    @SerialName("message") var message: String? = null,
    @SerialName("default") var default: ArrayList<User?>? = null
)

@Serializable
data class UserResponse(
        @SerialName("Name") var name: String? = null,
        @SerialName("Credit") var credit: String? = null,  
)


io.ktor.client.call.NoTransformationFoundException: No transformation found: class io.ktor.utils.io.ByteBufferChannel
```

And I am getting NoTransformationFoundException, I think it could be due to **data** object being empty, but how to fix this?

[According to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72611609/ktor-how-to-handle-an-empty-response), we can catch this exception, but I can't use this as I need other data to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Exception looks like you haven't install Json [content negotiation plugin](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization.html#add_content_negotiation_dependency), when creating ktor client. It should be like this:

```kotlin
val httpClient = HttpClient {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}
```

Then you can use this client like this:

```kotlin
val response: UserResponse = httpClient.get("URL").body()
```

Comment: I am using this, install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
        } with ignore unknown keys.

Comment: then you should check that your server returns right `Content-Type` header (application/json). And  if you are using DI double-check that this instance of HttpClient injects